# If a probability space has no measurable subsets with $P$ strictly between $0$ and $1$, then every random variable is constant a.s.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$ be a probability space such that $\forall F \in \mathfrak{F}, P(F) = 0 \ or \ 1$. Show that for all random variables X on $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$, $\exists \ c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that P(X=c)=1.
>
> Hint: Let $c = \inf(x:F_{X}(x)=1)$.

My attempt:

$P(X=c)$

$=P(X \in {c})$

$=P(\omega \in X^{-1}(c))$

$=0, 1 \because X^{-1}(c) \in \mathfrak{F}$

It is 1 because...c=$sup \Omega$ ?

And then I have to prove that c has to be finite. Am I then to show that $P(X=c) \neq 0 nor 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_X(\alpha) = p\{ \omega | X(\omega) \le \alpha \}$. It is not hard to show that $F_X$ is non-decreasing, continuous from the right, and $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} F_X(\alpha) = 1$. Furthermore, we have $F_X(\alpha) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $\alpha$. Consequently, there is some **finite** $\hat{\alpha}$ such that if $\alpha \ge \hat{\alpha}$, we have $F_X(\alpha) = 1$.

Let $c = \inf F_X^{-1} \{1\}$. Since $F_X$ is continuous from the right, we have $F_X(c) = 1$, and $F_X(c-{1 \over n}) = 0$ for all $n$. It follows that
$p\{ \omega | X(\omega) = c \} = p \cap_{n=1}^\infty \{ \omega | c - {1 \over n} < X(\omega) \le c \} = \lim_n ( F_X(c)- F_X(c-{1 \over n})) = 1$.

Edit: changed f to F

Comment: @BCLC: I'm pretty sure that he meant to write $\{0,1\}$ since $P(F)\in\{0,1\}$ for all $F$ by assumption. In particular it holds for $F=\{X\leq \alpha\}$.

Comment: Thanks but is it okay to replace the first equality of the last line with $\lim_{x \to c^{-}}(F_{X}(c)- F_{X}(x))$?

Comment: Also why must be c be a finite real number?

Comment: @StefanHansen Did you mean $\Omega \cap (X \leq \alpha)$ ?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @BCLC: In response to your comment above, you can replace the limit, however, since we are dealing with measures, I prefer to use explicit countable operations where possible. In this case, it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @BCLC: Since $F_X(\alpha) \to 1$, and $F_X(\alpha)$ can only take the values $\{0,1\}$ (this was an assumption), you **must** have $F_X(\alpha) = 1$ for some **finite** $\alpha$ (otherwise the limit would be zero).

Comment: @stefanhansen I don't think $(-\infty, \alpha]$ is an event/meas set?

Comment: @BCLC: For a real valued function $f$ to be a random variable, we must have that $f^{-1} (-\infty, x]$ is measurable for all $x$ (there are lots of equivalent definitions, this is typically the most convenient).

Comment: If a preimage of a set is measurable, the set is then measurable?

Comment: Typically $f$ is a random variable if $f^{-1}(-\infty,x]$ is measurable for all $x$. Hence it holds on the Borel sets generated by intervals. The events for a real values random variable are the Borel sets.

Comment: But, to answer your question, no. Take the function $f(x) = 1$ and any non-measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $f^{-1} A $ is either the empty set or the whole space, both of which are measurable.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Btw for the earlier comment, why would the limit be zero?

Comment: $F_X(\alpha)$ can only be zero or one. If it is zero for all $\alpha$, then the limit must also be zero.

Comment: What if $c=-\infty$? I can say that this makes $F = 1 on \mathbb{R}$ since if the lowest value (loosely speaking) that makes F become 1 is $-\infty$ which contradicts $lim_{x \to -\infty} F_{X}(x) = 0$. But that doesn't seem very precise, and I would much rather try to say this in the way of @drhab. I can't seem to justify that $\inf(x:F_{X}(x)=1) = \mathbb{R}$ if $c=-\infty$. After all $\inf A= -\infty$ <=/=> $A = \mathbb{R}$ unlike when $\inf A= \infty$ (which is necessary and sufficient that $A = \emptyset$).

Comment: Never mind found it on Wiki. Hahaha. "In analysis the infimum or greatest lower bound of a subset S of real numbers is denoted by inf(S) and is defined to be the biggest real number that is smaller than or equal to every number in S. If no such number exists (because S is not bounded below), then we define inf(S) = −∞. If S is empty, we define inf(S) = ∞ (an extended real number line)."

Comment: @StefanHansen Definitely no difference. Not sure what I was thinking then hahaha

Answer (score 1):

CDF $F$ can only have values in $\{0,1\}$ here.

Since it is not constant it will take both values.

$F$ is non-decreasing so $c=\inf\{x\mid F(x)=1\}\in\mathbb R$.

Also $F$ is right-continuous so $F(c)=\lim_{x\rightarrow c+}F(x)=1$.

For $x<c$ we have $F(x)=0$.

Proved is now that $F$ is the characteristic function of set $[c,\infty)$ wich is the CDF of a rv that is constant at $c$.

Comment: What happens if c is +/- $\infty$? I know $c \in \mathbb{R}$, but that is the 2nd question.

Comment: That cannot happen. There at least a point $x\in\mathbb R$ with $F(x)=1$ so that $c\leq x$ and there is at least a point $y\in\mathbb R$ with $F(y)=0$ so that $y\leq c$.

Comment: And if one were to claim that $c = x = \infty$?

Comment: $c=+\infty$ can only be achieved here if $F$ is constant and only takes value $0$. A CDF is never constant.

Comment: " 
c=+∞ can only be achieved here if F is constant and only takes value 0." because P(F)=0 or 1 for F={X≤α}?

Comment: Statement $c=+\infty$ is exactly the same statement as: $\left\{ x\mid F\left(x\right)=1\right\} =\emptyset$
or $\forall x\; F\left(x\right)<1$. Here $F\left(x\right)<1$ implies
directly $F\left(x\right)=0$ since $F\left(x\right)$ can only take
the values $0$ and $1$. So statement $c=+\infty$ is here exactly
the same statement as: $\forall x\; F\left(x\right)=0$. However a
function defined like this is not a CDF.

Comment: You mean c=+∞ is exactly the same statement as: {x∣F(x)=1 or ∀x 0<F(x)<1}=∅ ?

Comment: No, it is the same statement as $\left\{ x\mid F\left(x\right)=1\right\} =\emptyset$ of $\left\{ x\mid F\left(x\right)<1\right\} =\mathbb{R}$.
In general if $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ then $\inf A=+\infty\iff A=\emptyset$.
This is my last comment on this.

Comment: If by "this" you mean the $+\infty$ part, then how about $-\infty$ please?

Comment: Never mind found it on Wiki. Hahaha. "In analysis the infimum or greatest lower bound of a subset S of real numbers is denoted by inf(S) and is defined to be the biggest real number that is smaller than or equal to every number in S. If no such number exists (because S is not bounded below), then we define inf(S) = −∞. If S is empty, we define inf(S) = ∞ (an extended real number line)."

Answer (score 0):

If $c=\pm \infty$, then $(x:F_{X}(x)=1) = \emptyset$ or $\mathbb R$. Then $F_X(x) < 1 \ \forall x$ or $F_X(x) = 1 \ \forall x$.

By definition of such *finite* c, $$P(X \le c) = F_X(c) = 1 = F_X(d) \forall \ d \ge c$$

Now either $P(X \ge c) = 1$, in which case we're done or $P(X \ge c) = 0$.

Now $P(X \ge c) = 0 \to P(X < c) = 1 \to \exists \ d < c$ s.t. $P(X \le d) = 1$

But $\forall \ d < c$,

$$P(X \le d) = F_X(d) < 1 \to P(X \le d) = 0$$